# Simple iptables port forwarding with masquerading not working

Tags: vpn, iptables, nat, port-forwarding, tun

I'm trying to set up a simple VPN server on EC2 (Ubuntu 12.04) with the Android example ToyVpnServer.  Its instructions:

```
// There are several ways to play with this program. Here we just give an
// example for the simplest scenario. Let us say that a Linux box has a
// public IPv4 address on eth0. Please try the following steps and adjust
// the parameters when necessary.
//
// # Enable IP forwarding
// echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
//
// # Pick a range of private addresses and perform NAT over eth0.
// iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
//
// # Create a TUN interface.
// ip tuntap add dev tun0 mode tun
//
// # Set the addresses and bring up the interface.
// ifconfig tun0 10.0.0.1 dstaddr 10.0.0.2 up
//
// # Create a server on port 8000 with shared secret "test".
// ./ToyVpnServer tun0 8000 test -m 1400 -a 10.0.0.2 32 -d 8.8.8.8 -r 0.0.0.0 0
//
// This program only handles a session at a time. To allow multiple sessions,
// multiple servers can be created on the same port, but each of them requires
// its own TUN interface. A short shell script will be sufficient. Since this
// program is designed for demonstration purpose, it performs neither strong
// authentication nor encryption. DO NOT USE IT IN PRODUCTION!
```

I followed the above but replaced 10.* with 192.168.* since EC2's network has already taken 10.*:

```
$ echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
$ ip tuntap add dev tun0 mode tun
$ ifconfig tun0 192.168.0.1 dstaddr 192.168.0.2 up
$ iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
$ ./ToyVpnServer tun0 8000 test -m 1400 -a 192.168.0.2 32 -d 8.8.8.8 -r 0.0.0.0 0
```

I then establish the connection from the Android emulator, which works. When I then attempt a web request from the Android browser, the server gets packets, but they are not forwarded:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -i tun0 -n
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on tun0, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 65535 bytes
07:41:46.342823 IP 192.168.0.2.21668 > 8.8.8.8.53: 59997+ A? www.google.com. (32)
07:41:51.347913 IP 192.168.0.2.35397 > 8.8.8.8.53: 49390+ A? www.google.com. (32)
07:41:56.353276 IP 192.168.0.2.35397 > 8.8.8.8.53: 49390+ A? www.google.com. (32)
^C

$ sudo tcpdump -i eth0 not host 64.236.139.254 -n
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
^C
```

Other state of affairs:

```
$ ip route
default via 10.252.49.129 dev eth0  metric 100
10.252.49.128/26 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.252.49.153
192.168.0.2 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.1

$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 22:00:0a:fc:31:99 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.252.49.153/26 brd 10.252.49.191 scope global eth0
    inet6 fe80::2000:aff:fefc:3199/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 500
    link/none 
    inet 192.168.0.1 peer 192.168.0.2/32 scope global tun0

$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward 
1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I debugged this by adding:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j LOG --log-prefix "blah blah: "
```

which showed in /var/log/syslog:

```
Feb  1 10:53:47 ip-10-252-194-250 kernel: [9722772.386808] [UFW BLOCK] IN=tun0 OUT=eth0 MAC= SRC=192.168.0.2 DST=8.8.8.8 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=30129 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=64512 DPT=53 LEN=40
```

Simply using `ufw disable` seems to have done the trick.